# Event Call Back in interface

Tags: c#, oop, interface, callback

In my C# library I have an interface which exposes set of method to the consuming class.

Now my class need to raise some events. I was thinking to embed the event definition in my interface only so that client can register easily.

So I have this definition:

```
public delegate void EventCallBack(object sender, EventArgs eventData);
```

And my interface contains this line:

```
EventCallBack NotifyListener;
```

Now I am getting following error:

> Interface cannot contain definition

How do I incorporate my event definition in interface only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `event` keyword, like this:

```
event EventCallBack NotifyListener;
```

as explained in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak9w5846.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`EventCallBack NotifyListener;` is a declaration of a field - interfaces don't have fields.

You have to declare an event, which encapsulate access to a delegate field, the same way properties encapsulate access to regular fields.

```
event EventCallBack NotifyListener;
```